Looking for help on a digital multimeter
Does anyone use an IDM-8341 in this group?
I bought this a while back (second hand) for its logging capabilities but now I cannot find the device drivers and software Excel add-in anywhere.
I have some important testing happening soon so wondering if anyone uses it and can maybe share the drivers. I have sent an email to rs-pro and gwinstek but haven’t received a response after a week or so.

(GDM-8341?)

Drivers for what exactly? Windows? Some other program? USB or GBIP?

Apologies for not being clear. Yes i am looking for Windows 10 Drivers for USB.

@greybeard - GDM-8341 have drivers and excel add-in on GW Instek. But a while back RS Pro rebranded and started selling them as IDM-8341. So the drivers and Excel add-in is different for this. I was kind of able to change Device drivers so a port is enumerated for IDM-8341 but excel add-in still didn't work.

https://docs.rs-online.com/8a56/0900766b81734963.pdf

Thanks for the datasheet @Antonio51 - if only they posted a link to download the stuff in their datasheet. everything will be so easy.

Thanks @Antonio51 - but these are different drivers to what i need. RS Pro rebranded and started selling them as IDM-8341. So the drivers and Excel add-in is different for this as compared to GDM-8341. (i tried using these nevertheless and also tried to amend the drivers to work for IDM-8341 but was unsuccessful)

Ok. I deleted. They was the same as @D.A.S. shows ... :-)

No problem - appreciate you going through the trouble of finding and sharing the link :) with me.

https://www.gwinstek.com/en-global/download/index?cate=129&subcate=272&ser=670&down=62&key
See if this solves your problems

A while back RS Pro rebranded and started selling them as IDM-8341 and the drivers and Excel add-in is different for IDM-8341. I was kind of able to change Device drivers so a port is enumerated for IDM-8341 in Device Manager but excel add-in still didn't work (so i probably didn't amend device drivers correctly) I really hope RS-PRO made drivers and excel add-on. But i cannot find them anywhere and there customer support is also not that great (by that i mean timely response - i am sure they have some capable people working). Thanks for your response DAS.

I can't imagine why they would change it as Keysight is their partner for test & measurement https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2HIjVWT75kk&list=PLqnIaXrARxXHYp8FJeR6AkSAADdpt4K0d&index=2.

I see RS as a distributer only.  Ask gwinstek for the drivers

Thanks, I had already sent an email to them as well a while back but haven't heard from them as well. maybe everyone is closed for new year break...

must be so call the operator
